# JSP mod operator not working

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying this but its going to else part always

```
 <c:forEach items="${records}" var="field" varStatus="counter">

    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${counter.count mod 2 == 0}">
            <div class="classEven">
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <div class="classOdd">
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
        sample text here

        </div>          

 </c:forEach>
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Have you tried with `${(counter.count mod 2) == 0}`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could also use `${counter.count % 2 == 0}`

Answer (score 1):

```
test = ${counter.index mod 2 == 0}
```

Answer (score -2):

Separated jstl from html + plus no math for you artsy types

```
<c:set var="row" value="Even" />
<c:forEach items="${records}" var="field" varStatus="counter">
<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${row eq 'Odd'}">
            <c:set var="row" value="Even" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="row" value="Odd" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose> 

       <div class="class${row}">

        sample text here

        </div>          


 </c:forEach>
```